# tab-slide-out 1.4.1 add a link or button to toggle open/close

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using tab-slide-out 1.4.1 .. download is [here](http://code.google.com/p/tab-slide-out/downloads/detail?name=jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.4.1.js&can=2&q=):

It says that version 1.4.1 includes the ability to add a link or button to toggle the open/close of the tab 1.4.1

My problem is that it does say how it's done. Has anyone done this or know how it's done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$(".handle").click();
```

Comment: write it inside

jQuery(document).ready(function($){});

so it will execute it after the document loads.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source of version 1.4.1](http://code.google.com/p/tab-slide-out/source/browse/trunk/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.4.js) it looks like you need to pass a selector into the `toggleButton` setting, which basically just duplicates the functionality of `tabHandle`.

e.g:

```
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle',                         //class of the element that will be your tab -doesnt have to be an anchor
    pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',     //relative path to the image for the tab *required*
    imageHeight: '133px',                         //height of tab image *required*
    imageWidth: '44px',                           //width of tab image *required*
    toggleButton: '.button'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent several days on the Open/Close issue with TabSlideout.  Here is the solution I found.  Both answers from freejosh and Satch3000 give part of the solution.

First, with pre-1.4 versions of Tabslideout, you could create the open/close effect with:

```
$(".handle").click();
```

listed after the initial TabSlideout declaration.  So it would look like this:

```
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle',                         //class of the element that will be your tab -doesnt have to be an anchor
    pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',     //relative path to the image for the tab *required*
    imageHeight: '133px',                         //height of tab image *required*
    imageWidth: '44px',                           //width of tab image *required*
});
$(".handle").click();
```

Now, in your HTML, you would create a control, with class "handle" that would open/close the tab.  So, the following would be suitable.  A user would then click this LINK, and the tab would open.

```
<a href="#" class="handle">Open Tab</a>
```

You can go further, and define a Close button.  You define it again, under the original tabslideout code:

```
$(’.close-button’).click(function(){$(’.handle’).click();});
```

And the corresponding calling control:

> ```
> <a href="#" class="close-button">CloseTab</a>
> ```

### Version 1.4.1

With Version 1.4.1 of Tabslideout, the author fixed up the tabslideout and included the ability to open/close the tab using 'Togglebutton'.  You have to declare it in the initial tabslideout declaration as Satch mentioned:

```
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle',                         //class of the element that will be your tab -doesnt have to be an anchor
    pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',     //relative path to the image for the tab *required*
    imageHeight: '133px',                         //height of tab image *required*
    imageWidth: '44px',                           //width of tab image *required*
    toggleButton: '.button'
});
```

Note the last line togglebutton.

Then on your page, you have a control that runs the open/close:

```
<a href="#" class="togglebutton">Open Tab</a>
```

**References:**
The original author spends alot of time on his own blog answering questions.  I combed through his 152 comments for the above code.

http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/#comments

I also found Mark's solution to make the tab dynamic very useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700304/1198613